# Solving a curvilinear integral based on an equation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-integration

Please help me with the following integral
$$
\int_C{\frac{\sin\pi z}{(3z-\pi i)^3}}dz
$$

Where $C$ is the defined by the ecuation of $|z| =1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Some guiding questions: What are the poles of the integrand? Where are they relative to $|z|=1$? What are the residues at the poles inside the contour? What does the residue theorem tell you? If you've already answered some of these questions, consider adding your answers to the question body.